# How to upload a pdf file from input with jquery to php?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I am using a wizard to complete a user profile on my system. In step 7, I use the wizard to load a pdf document. I want the document to load automatically when selected from the imput, but I am having the following complications.

It is worth mentioning that I want to load it with ajax (so that the process is automatic) and send it to php to save it on the server.

The wizard is this (as reference):
https://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/59e5e1ya/

My Input:

```
<div class="box">
    <input type="file" name="file-7" id="file-7" class="inputfile inputfile-6" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple />
        <label for="file-7">
            <span></span> 
            <strong>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="17" viewBox="0 0 20 17"><path d="M10 0l-5.2 4.9h3.3v5.1h3.8v-5.1h3.3l-5.2-4.9zm9.3 11.5l-3.2-2.1h-2l3.4 2.6h-3.5c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.1l-.8 2.3h-6l-.8-2.2c-.1-.1-.1-.2-.2-.2h-3.6l3.4-2.6h-2l-3.2 2.1c-.4.3-.7 1-.6 1.5l.6 3.1c.1.5.7.9 1.2.9h16.3c.6 0 1.1-.4 1.3-.9l.6-3.1c.1-.5-.2-1.2-.7-1.5z"/>
                </svg> 
                Find pdf &hellip;
            </strong>
        </label>
</div>
```

[image]

This is my js

```
$('#file-7').change(function(e){
    var file_data = this.files[0];
    //var file_data = $(this).prop('files')[0];
    console.log(file_data);
        if(file_data != undefined) {
            var datos = new FormData();
            datos.append('sendpdf', true);                  
            datos.append('pdf', file_data);
            $.ajax({
                url:"views/ajax.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:datos,
                contentType:false,
                processData:false,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $("#loading").removeClass('hidden');
                },
                success: function(regreso){
                    $("#loading").addClass('hidden');

                    console.log(regreso);
                }
            });
        }  
});
```

This is my ajax.php

```
if (isset($_POST["sendpdf"])) {
    var_dump($_POST['pdf']);
}
```

The error:

[image]

```
console.log(file_data);
```

[image]

Thanks for help me.

Comment: What does `console.log(file_data);` show?

Comment: @KalimahApps Ok, I already updated the post.

Comment: I am not sure about the exact issue. Can try to encode the file object? Use this line `datos.append('pdf', btoa(file_data));` and in your PHP file you can add `base64_decode ( $_POST['pdf'])`

Comment: @KalimahApps Excellent, I already receive the file in php, but I think it arrives empty http://prntscr.com/pzdg7a

Comment: Its not empty. It is an object. Try to use `json_decode(base64_decode ( $_POST['pdf']))`

Comment: @KalimahApps YES, I do just that, look at the result http://prntscr.com/pzdib2 :(

Comment: Then I think this is the problem. Data is being transferred. It is possible that because PDF needs to be transferred as a BLOB object.

Comment: @KalimahApps Ok, thanks, I will try this example https://gist.github.com/nolanlawson/62e747cea7af01542479

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only I need receive in php with these code:

```
$_FILES['file']
```